# PHP: reverse able unique hash

Tags: php, hash, unique, urlencode

I'm building a browser in PHP (browser in browser (: just for fun ) ,  and i have come across a major problem. I need to short a URL into something shorter (encoded) which can be reverse able.

for example now i process the page like that :

```
site.com/stackoverflow.com/questions/9217271/php-reverse-able-unique-hash
```

and that's too long , i was looking for something that will be like that :

```
site.com/sftDblt
```

which the "sftDblt" can be reverse able to "stackoverflow.com/questions/9217271/php-reverse-able-unique-hash"

is there anything you know about that can help?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to store the hash and the resulting URL in a database table. You can then look things up from there

Comment: Just generate and store the unique code in a database as the primary key, associated to the full url.

Comment: @Pekka user visit 500 pages daily * 10k users = 5M rows a day. is there not any other way?

Comment: @MorSela, Let's back up a bit. Why are you needing to store URL's for multiple users in a single application?

Comment: As others have said, you can only do this using a database and encoding the IDs of the rows that have the full URL. Otherwise, what you’re looking for is incredible compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash can't be reversed. You should go with http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 3):

Why not just start a counter for the key? Keep track of the url and counter in a database.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is (basically) impossible without a lookup table. You can obviously use standard compression algorithms, but then you'd have to encode the compressed data as an ASCII string (base-64, etc), which would possibly be larger than the original string.

Comment: Agreed.  The OP wants a hash table.  A hash is, by definition, not reversible.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: use the first letter of each word in the title and save it in a column in the post table.

Using your example (site.com/stackoverflow.com/questions/9217271/php-reverse-able-unique-hash), the url would be "prauh".

If the url happens to exists in the DB, you can add 2 random alphanumeric characters then check your DB again to see if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

I created a small class to do this sort of thing with the help of some commenters.
http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash

Comment: Not working anymore